# what is a GTK theme engine?

Tags: themes, gtk

short and simple:
what is a GTK engine vs a theme etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GTK, an *engine* changes the look of the widgets drawn, often to match the native widget set on a particular OS, to control properties such as widget curvature or animations.  An engine is software running on your machine.

*Themes* are a general term for all of the artwork & the color schemes used when rendering everything you see.  It's not a GTK-unique term.  Two different engines could use the same theme files as input, but the final result would be rendered a bit differently.  Themes are a (mostly) static collection of files.

Answer (score 1):

Both themes and engines can be used to make your programs look different.  A theme is simpler than an engine.  It typically just involves creating a collection of image files that get used to construct window borders and widgets.  An engine is like a plugin to a web browser that actually runs new code to generate the borders and widgets.  Engines are more complex to create, but this allows them to create fancier effects.

Answer (score 0):

The theme engine is the display backend that uses a theme to style windows.